# Angular - ui-router wait for a promise before route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using `Angular 1.5.8` and `angular-ui-router 0.3.2`.
I need to resolve an authentication method on every route change.

I dont want to add the resolve property for each route so I created this in `App.run`

```
//check permissions

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (evt, toState) {
    if ($localStorage.token || toState.authenticated) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common = {
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + $localStorage.token,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        };

        permissionAPI.me()
            .then(function(data){
                $rootScope.user = data;
            })
            .catch(function(){
                if(toState.authenticated) {
                    $rootScope.logout();
                }
            })
    }
    else {
        if(toState.authenticated) {
            $rootScope.logout();
        }
    }
});
```

`

It is usually working well, But I noticed that many times the application is routing before the promise `permissionAPI.me()` resolved and that causing errors later.

How can I make sure the route will take effect just after that promise?

Or, how can I make a main `resolve` for all of my routes by passing that promise from `$stateChangeStart` ?

Thank you!

Comment: this will *always* route after the promise starts, not when the promise is resolved.  The canonical way to handle this is to create an abstract route which has the `resolve` for all the routes under it.  Unfortunately, trying to use a Promise which is asynchronous by nature as a synchronous function is not a sound solution.

Comment: how can I connect that promise from `$stateChangeStart` to resolve function?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies

Comment: That is not what I meant, How can I pass the promise from the `$stateChangeStart` to the `ui-router`?

Answer (score 2):

Create an app state! Abstract states are useful for if you need to access data consistently across your application, but don't want to have that data associated with a specific view.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', { 
            url: '/app/',
            template: '<div ui-view></div>',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            abstract: true,
            resolve: {
                ActiveUser: function (AuthService) {
                    return AuthService.whoAmI();
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'app.home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            resolve: {
                Categories: function (ActiveUser, MessagesService) {
                    return MessagesService.getAll(User);
                }
            }
        });
```

You can then access that data in subsequent resolve blocks or in your controllers like `app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function (ActiveUser) {});` as long as your controller is in a child state of `'app'`. This is achieved with the naming convention `'app.'`

Comment: is it possible in that way to pass `toState` to the `AuthService`?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to resolve whether or not a user can enter a state?

Comment: On `$stateChangeStart` I'd call `AuthService.validateRouteAccess(ActiveUser)` in your `AppCtrl` on `$rootScope`. Then I'd do like a `$rootScope.emit('Auth.routeUnauthorized', ...)` which you could handle differently in different routes (or just handle it all in the base controller).